# Apache shows empty Index of even though there are files in /var/www/

Tags: apache2

[image]

Even though I have files placed in my var/www/ folder and apache2 is running, I don't get any files listed. Also I can't access any files directly and inserting an index.html file does nothing.

I'm on trusty 64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 14.04 the default `DocumentRoot` is not `/var/www/` but `/var/www/html/`.

You can change that in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf` (or whatever site config you re using).

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I'm shocked to see that they changed it? Was there a good reason to do so?

Comment: When you have multiple virtual hosts it is common to use  sub folders of `/var/www/` for each host. In that case `/var/www/` as `DocumentRoot` may make information available that you want want to keep private. Thus it is a bad default.